# html columns stacking not side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Hi y'all I'm trying to understand why my columns are stacking on top of each other instead of being side by side.

My goal is to have my recipes component in the center of the page and have my grocery sidebar be aligned with the recipe component.

This is what the website currently looks like. I'm trying to get the toggle side bar button to be inline with the recipes component
[image]

Here's my main apps html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="recipe-column">
        <recipes></recipes>
    </div>
    <div class="grocery-column">
        <app-grocery-sidebar></app-grocery-sidebar>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the main apps css

```
  .column {
    float: left;
  }
  
  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  .row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
  }

  .recipe-column{
      float:left;
      padding-left:10%;
  }

  .grocery-column{
      float:left;
  }
```

My goal is to have the recipe component taking up the whole page and have the "toggle sidenav" button in the upperleft corner in line with the navbar. So if anyone has any ideas on how to accomplish this please let me know.

Bonus Question: I also can't figure out how to get my navbar push to the top of the page, I don't like that space. So if you know how to make that happen I would love to hear it.

Comment: Usually `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` fixes the problem

Comment: @hemnathmouli I tried adding 
     `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` but It didn't work

Comment: I would [learn flexbox](https://scrimba.com/course/gflexbox)

Comment: @Sam I've never heard of flexbox. Thank you so much for that resource you mentioned! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to edit out `clear:both;`. For space above navbar you can try `margin:0px; padding:0px;`.